# Is this the correct way to formulate my linear program?

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, linear-programming

Have I written the correct linear program for this problem:
"A supermarket has decided to allow you to make for them the sandwiches they sell at your production company. Your company can make three different sandwiches, Chicken Salad, Chicken Club and Cheese & Bacon. Below is a table which shows the amount of ingredients in grams that each sandwich requires:

[image]

The total amount of time (measured in minutes) to make one of each sandwich is
listed below, together with the price that the supermarket will pay to purchase one
of each:[image]

It is given that we may treat all quantities as continuous.

Suppose that you have 5000g of chicken, 2500g of cheese, 1500g of bacon, 6000g
of bread, and 500g of Mayonnaise available from your supplier each day, and a
total of 120 person-hours (= 7200 total minutes) of labour available each day.
Write a linear program to find a production plan that maximises your daily
revenue.

My program looks like this:

Let $x_0,x_1,x_2$ represent the Chicken salad, chicken club and cheese & bacon sandwich respectivley.

$$\text{Maximise } 1.05x_0 + 1.40x_1 + 0.95x_2 \text{ (Profit)}$$
$$\text{Subject to } 40x_0 + 25x_1 \le 5000 \text{ (Chicken)}$$
$$20x_1 +30x_2 \le 2500 \text{ (Cheese)}$$
$$10x_1+20x_2 \le 1500 \text{ (Bacon)}$$
$$22x_0 +5x_1 +5x_2 \le 500 \text{ (Mayonaise)}$$
$$60x_0 +90x_1 +60x_2 \le 6000 \text{ (Bread)}$$
$$3.5x_0 +5.8x_1 + 0.9x_2 \le 7200 \text{ (Minutes of labour)}$$
$$x_0,x_1,x_2 \ge 0$$

Comment: Yes, it is fine. The objective function represents the (daily) revenue rather than the profit, since the costs are not regarded.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.

Comment: You're welcome.